# How do I reassign Label text with Tkinter from a different function

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *




# reassigns variables for label and button texts
def Ctrack(vname, vvalue):
    #global vname
    vname = vvalue
    
    #place holder to check which button has been clicked
    print(vname)
    
    #labeltext = reassign label text bas
    
    
# creates labels and buttons
def buttons():
    root = Tk()
    
    #first label
    
    winlabel = Label(root, text =labeltext )
    winlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    #first button
    but1 = Button(root, text = "button 1", command = lambda *args: Ctrack(0, 1))
    but1.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    #second button
    but2 = Button(root, text = "button 2", command = lambda *args: Ctrack(0, 2))
    but2.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    root.mainloop()

buttons()
```

(first time using Stackoverflow)

How do I reassign the label text in my buttons function to whatever I assign the variable in the Ctrack function?

Comment: You will have to declare it as a global variable(`global winlabel`) inside `buttons()` and then call it inside `Ctrack()` like `winlabel['text'] = 'What ever you want'`

Comment: Your code will raise exception: `NameError: name 'labeltext' is not defined` at the line `winlabel = Label(root, text =labeltext)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the Ctrack() function the ability to post the Label on the root window.
If you go with that approach, you can add 'root' as an argument in Ctrack() and then declare-and-pack the Label within the Ctrack() function.